# Redis and Siglnar Occasional Hangs SocketFailure on EVAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, signalr

We are using Redis:  2.8.2400 and SignalR 2.2.0

We can see in our logs that we have occasional hangs.

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on EVAL
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.ScaleoutStream.Send(Func`2 send, Object state)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.Connection.Send(ConnectionMessage message)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.Outgoing(IHubOutgoingInvokerContext context)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubPipelineModule.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<BuildOutgoing>b__19(IHubOutgoingInvokerContext context)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.SignalProxy.TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result)
 at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , List`1 )
 at SR.BusPortal.WebApi.Hubs.SearchHub.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<SearchInternal>b__0(List`1 x) in D:\Continua\Agent\Ws\37347\Source\WEB\src\SR.BusPortal.WebApi\SR.BusPortal.WebApi\Hubs\SearchHub.cs:line 141
 at SR.BusPortal.Providers.Faciliators.SearchExecutioner.PrepareResultsAsync(IEnumerable`1 connections, Boolean deliverVerifications, Func`2 callback) in D:\Continua\Agent\Ws\37347\Source\WEB\src\SR.BusPortal.WebApi\SR.BusPortal.Providers\Faciliators\SearchExecutioner.cs:line 120
 at SR.BusPortal.Providers.Faciliators.SearchExecutioner.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<SearchAsync>b__0(List`1 x) in D:\Continua\Agent\Ws\37347\Source\WEB\src\SR.BusPortal.WebApi\SR.BusPortal.Providers\Faciliators\SearchExecutioner.cs:line 216

 StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on EVAL
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.ScaleoutStream.Send(Func`2 send, Object state)
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.Connection.Send(ConnectionMessage message)
```

I could reduce it to mostly fail on this specific line of code:

```
 Clients.Caller.SearchResults(connectionModels);
```

which is primarly the return of the data to the client.

Now I'm thinking about wether it would be a could idea to catch it in this case the specific exception and try again. But I feel unsure wether this may lead to duplicate results in the client?

Any advice on the error itself or about the retry idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was not the redis server. We used [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis)  which uses internal  1.0.316 StackExchange.Redis but the current version is 1.0.488.

The Problems were only occuring with this StackExchange.Redis version and as the support of Redis For Windows told me they already experienced similar problem in the past with it as client connections werent always released.

For our caches we used ServiceSTack.Redis and they were abled to read and write to redis even when signalR created the error.

In our case we are just using sticky sessions so that we can remove the backplanbe for signalR.

Another way would be to use another backplane or wait thill signalR updates the StackExchange.Redis version

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Redis 2.8.2400, you can try to update your server to 3.0.501

Comment: did the update solved it for you ? are you using any cluster / sentinel functionality?

Comment: We also are thinking about this about, but with the first version we had a very bad hang, thats why i fear it a little ; )

Comment: Yes it solved the issue,  we used redis cluster feature

Comment: do you also use sentinels ? and do you also had sudden hangs where for one or two minutes it signalR wasn't replying at all ? sorry just too corious as this problem currently drives me crazy

Comment: Since we merged to 3.0 I didn't receive any other error with Redis, maybe you can try on a test environement before updating.

Comment: in my case it fixed the gien error but after some hors it reaches the maxmemory limit and fails to clear the data (event if all are having expire dates and is set tu remove them with LRU cachen) just to get an idea, how data do you have in there? and what is you maxmemory set to ?

Comment: I'm using redis for caching only little datas, but the service is runing for months. For the client part I use the `ServiceStack.Redis` client. Maybe the problem comes from your client library.

Comment: ah ok this may be the difference, one year ago it was also stbale here. but in the meanwhile we have multiple gigabyte data :-/ I Just wonder if the Linux version would be much butter, as SO uses them also and they would have even more data

Comment: Yes linux version is so much better ! If you can migrate your Redis server on a linux it's the best option.